# how to install apk file in emulator using adb?

Tags: android, android-emulator

**c:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install foo.apk** (Platform 3.1)

**137 KB/s (14948 bytes in 0.106s)**

**pkg: /data/local/tmp/foo.apk**

**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]**

I am trying to install it shows like above. i am new to android please help me.

Comment: its seems like u trying to install the higher version apk file in the lower version's device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RAJU
If you set the all java_SDk and Android_sdk in environment variable in your system than it is good to handle command from any where so check this steps:

Step1:If you don't set than Fisrt you need to set environment variable of android-sdk like this C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools And this is my location of android sdk your could be different .

Step2:If you use eclipse than create avd with the your application version specified .Than run your  emulator .

Step3:After Run That Emulator sucessfully,than open cmd if you use Window than write this command: adb install "E:\path for your apk" at this time make sure that there is only one devices is running ok

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, the compatibility is the problem. I tried it and got vending.apk is only installed but GoogleServicesFramework.apk is not installed it is showing the error as FAILURE[INSTALL-PARSE-FAILED-NO-CERTIFICATE]